# How to rewrite a line in a CSV using python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm having some trouble with my code - I have a csv file and I have to save the first line in the csv as a list. Then I have to clear the file and rewrite the line using the list. This is my code:

```
import csv

f = open('PlateBook.csv','r')
reader = f.readlines()

for row in reader:
    outrow = list(row) 

    with open('PlateBook.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        f.truncate
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        data =  [outrow]

        a.writerows(data)
```

The trouble is, when I open the csv in Excel it's clearly wrong. Each character fills up a cell - I want the file to look exactly the same as when I written the file.

Comment: can you fix the indentation? This program can have two very different meaning depending on the fact if `with ...` is under the `for` loop or not.

Comment: tried `a.writerow(data)` ??

Comment: Also when you "open" your file in excel, how exactly do you do it? There's a possibility that Excel interprets it as csv, and automatically separates the characters. Try opening it in a notepad or some text editor. @SIslam; it's not an "unvalid" line.

Comment: Opening `f` for reading then opening it again for writing while it's still open and use for reading seems very error-prone to me.  I suggest to try to code without doing that.  Either save intermediate results somewhere or use 'wrt' mode for file opening.

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward text manipulation. Why don't you show what a couple of lines of the original file look like and what you want your final file to look like and I'm sure you'll get the correct solution quickly.

Comment: I just want to replicate the line exactly as it is. If the line was strawberries and cream, I want to clear the line and write strawberries and cream, exactly as it was. I know it's not that hard, but I'm still learning how to code in Python.

Comment: @GabrielOwens; yep, I understand, and there's several other things wrong with your program, but it'd be nice if you figured it out on your own. Variety of comments here solve different issues you currently have. But just for the sake of the argument, have you tried to open the file in a text editor? Notepad, Notepad++,  whatever of the kind? If you have, you'd probably notice that it wasn't written properly. Excel is more than just text editing program and is probably built to handle these cases, therefore you don't see it as wrong, just separated in 2 different cells.

Answer (score 0):

From the issue you describe, I guess that you don't want to do

```
outrow = list(row)
```

which simply creates a list of each charater, but more something like

```
outrow = row.split(',')
```

which create a list of the string separated by commas.

Or, **even better**, use a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv), so it handle quotes and all little details of csv's.

Here is an *untested* sample code of what you should do.

```
import csv

with open('PlateBook.csv','rt') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader( input_file )
    with open('PlateBook.temp.csv','wt') as output_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter( output_file, fieldnames = csvreader.fieldnames )
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow( row )

#So far we didnot touch the original file, so if the process
#fails, nothing is left in half-processed state.
import os
os.remove( 'PlateBook.csv' )
os.rename( 'PlateBook.temp.csv', 'PlateBook.csv' )
```